# How to separate DB connection initialization as a package in Go?

Tags: go, package

I have two packages, `main` and `db`.
However, I get `"DB declared and not used"` error.

db.go

```
package db

import (
  "database/sql"
)

var DB *sql.DB

func Connect() {
  DB, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:xxxx@/xxxx")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
  }
}

func Close() {
  DB.Close()
}
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    // "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
  "github.com/****/****/config"
  "github.com/****/****/db"
)

var tpl *template.Template

func init() {
    tpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/*.gohtml"))
}

func main() {
    Connect()
    defer Close()
    loadRoutes()
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you are using `:=`, the [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations), which declares a new `DB` variable for the scope of the `Connect` function. That means that the `DB` declared at the package level is a different variable from the `DB` declared inside `Connect`. To fix the problem, inside `Connect` just above `sql.Open`, declare an error variable (i.e. `var err error`) and then use `=`; i.e. `DB, err = sql.Open(...`. Example: https://play.golang.org/p/3XglGr-2LZa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Golang is strict about variable declaration, it is also mentioned in the [Golang FAQs](https://golang.org/doc/faq#unused_variables_and_imports):

> The presence of an unused variable may indicate a bug, while unused
>   imports just slow down compilation, an effect that can become
>   substantial as a program accumulates code and programmers over time.
>   For these reasons, Go refuses to compile programs with unused
>   variables or imports, trading short-term convenience for long-term
>   build speed and program clarity.

It's easy to address the situation, though. Use the blank identifier to let unused things persist while you're developing.

```
_, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:Berlin2018@/jplatform")
```

But since you want db instance by creating a connection. I suggest to use it either by returning from the function OR You can check for the connection if it is working or not by sending ping to the database server as:

```
var DB *sql.DB

func Connect() {
    DB, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:Berlin2018@/jplatform")
    if err = DB.Ping(); err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
}
```

Or you can create a struct which you can use anywhere you want including use of method receiver for every function which require db connection for querying the database as

```
type Env struct {
    db *sql.DB
}

func Connect() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:Berlin2018@/jplatform")
    _ = &Env{db: db}
}

func(env *Env) getDataFromDatabase(){}
```

Comment: thanks, @Himanshu! On the solution using the `strct` approach, though, how should I close the database connection? Would it be possible do `defer` it?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using your `DB` variable on `db.go`:

```
package db

import (
  "database/sql"
)

var DB *sql.DB

func Connect() {
  con, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:Berlin2018@/jplatform")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
  }
  DB = con
}

func Close() {
  DB.Close()
}
```